# Drag Drop a ListBoxItem on the same ListBox in Delphi xe firemonkey

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, delphi-xe, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

I need a way to sort `listboxItems` within the same `listbox` in a mobile application.

I have put a `listbox` in the form, and added some `listboxitems`, I have set `DargMode` of `listboxitems` to `dmAutomatic`, I have written this event handlers:

```
procedure TForm1.ListBox1DragDrop(Sender: TObject; const Data: TDragObject;
  const Point: TPointF);
var
  DropedTarget : TListBoxItem;
begin
  DropedTarget := ListBox1.ItemByPoint(Point.X, Point.Y);
  if (DropedTarget <> nil) then
    (Data.Source as TListBoxItem).Index := DropedTarget.Index;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListBox1DragOver(Sender: TObject; const Data: TDragObject;
  const Point: TPointF; var Operation: TDragOperation);
begin
  if Data.Source is TListBoxItem then
    Operation := TDragOperation.Move;
end;
```

The problem is items in the list box can't be dragged at all.

What I missed?

Comment: Delphi XE is an old version from before FireMonkey was included. It would help people to answer if you say which version you are actually using.

Comment: @MikeSutton I thought that folks will get it from `var Operation: TDragOperation` in parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check, that you have checked the `AllowDrag` property of `ListBox1`.

And check that to **set** the `ListBox1` DragMode **is** `Manual`.